# module.exports value not found when used in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, eslint, es6-modules

Not sure why, I can import this file and use `expect` in my test files just fine, *but* I am getting an eslint error:

```
error  expect not found in '../../testImports' import/named
```

This is where I export, `testImports.js`:

```
import chai from 'chai'
const expect = require('chai').expect
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { jsdom } from './jsdom'

module.exports = {
  BrowserRouter,
  expect,
  jsdom
}
```

And I'm importing as so into files: `import { expect } from '../../testImports'`.

Comment: yea sorry one sec

Comment: just added that while you were typing :)

Comment: crap I know what it is, I'm using ES6 imports with node modules duh

Comment: weird that it still works though....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `eslint-plugin-import` only picks up on ES6 module system exports, not ES5. They mean the same thing, the plugin just doesn't catch it. Since the plugin doesn't see you've exported anything, it reports the error, but there's nothing actually wrong about your code. If you want to get rid of the error, just use ES6's `export`:

```
export {
  BrowserRouter,
  expect,
  jsdom
};
```

Comment: cool, I changed my testImports to just use es6 export instead of node's module.exports, seems to clear it up

Comment: @PositiveGuy Yep. `module.exports = { ... }` is functionally the same as `export { ... }`, one is ES5 and the other ES6 if you were wondering why it was working despite the warning.

Comment: Thank you! Worked. ESLint should have given smarter warning for those who are new to JS.